# Why do we use += when adding an event to a button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

I am new to ASP.NET and I have a question about adding a event handler to a button (html server control) when the page is loaded.

This code is in C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Submit.ServerClick+=Submit_ServerClick;
}
```

Here, my question is why do we need to add += and what is its significance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am new to ASP.NET and I have a question about adding a event handler
>   to a button

You do not need to manually bind click event. Instead, you can just bind it at front end.

***History*** - old **ASP.Net Website Project** (10 years ago) did not have designer file, so we manually had to bind it inside Page_Load. We do not have to do that anymore in **ASP.Net Web Application**.

### ASPX

```
<asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server"  Text="Submit" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click"/>
```

### Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do something after post back.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `+=` adds an event subscription delegate to an `event`. In contrast `-=` removes (un-subscribes) the event delegate from the `event`. An event delegate can have multiple assignments to the single delegate and each one will be executed (according to the event handler specifications).

If you consider the sytnax of `+=` in constract to other operations.

```
int x = 1 //x equals 1
x += 5; //x now equals 6
```

Therefore it makes sense that when you are adding to a subscription to use the same syntax.

Now there are multiple different ways to subscribe to an event handler however they all begin with `+=`. [MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx)

```
DoEvent += doEvent; //standard assignement by passing the method delegate. Advantage you can unsubscribe
DoEvent += (o, e) => { }; //lambada assignment event arguaments
DoEvent += delegate { }; //inline delegate assignement with no event arguments
DoEvent += delegate (object o, EventArgs e) { }; //inline delegate assignment with event argumes
```

Which ever you choose the end result is the same, you are subscribing to an event from a control

Answer (score 0):

That is just the operator that Microsoft chose to use to add to the multi-cast delegate which events are. You can add more than 1 event handler to an event with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you have some public property to store delegates

```
public Action PublicDelegate { get; set; }
```

And some code uses this property:

```
PublicDelegate += () => {/* some code */};
```

How to protect your property from overwriting, for example:

```
PublicDelegate = null;
```

To protecting from such code, an "event" keyword is coming.

The "event" keyword is just a syntax sugar, which protects your property of delegate type from overwriting. You can only add (+=) or remove (-=) from this property, but you can not directly change whole property.

Answer (score 0):

Think of an event like a list of chores. When the event is invoked, each of the chores is performed in the order they were added. They can also be subtracted. So when you use += you are adding another chore to the end of the list.

If you only ever have one chore in the list, using += feels a bit like overkill, but you're not allowed to use = as with delegates because that would erase all other chores in the list if there were any.

So the main reason events differ from delegates is that events only allow the chore list to be modified one at a time; this is what mandates the use of += or -= exclusively.